# Backing up Java?

Tags: java, backup

I'm currently using Java and I'm looking for a program that saves a new version of what I'm doing each time I compile. I don't mind if it doesn't run, I can go in and edit the class name to make it match the .java name afterwards. As I'm a beginner, I keep getting caught by overextending myself and then breaking the project I'm working on irreparably. I'm just looking for a way to go back to a safe state.

I'm sure their are programs for this, but because I don't know the collective noun for them, finding one is next to impossible.

All help is much appreciated.

Comment: You should look into revision control systems (such as Git).

Comment: Definitely look into using a VCS. Some IDE's like Eclipse also give you a buffer of history you can recover code from.

Comment: Right now I'm using Textpad as the simplicity suits my lack of skills. Eclipse and other IDEs are quite overwhelming at the moment, when I'm already trying to learn so much just getting a grasp of coding. GIT seems to be right up my street. It can store locally as well as online, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is [revision control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control).  This works independent of the language you're dealing with, since all the VCS is concerned with is the state of the software at a particular snapshot in time.

Some recommendations:

- [Subversion](http://subversion.tigris.org)
- [Git](http://git-scm.com)
- [Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com)

[IntelliJ IDEA](http://jetbrains.com/idea) also comes with a built-in local revision system, which allows you to visit a particular file's history.  It'd still be preferable to use either Git or Subversion.

There are also sites that you can host your project on to better preserve your project, such as [Github](http://github.com) or [Google Code](http://code.google.com).  Github uses...Git, but Google Code will allow you to use a few others, such as Subversion and Mercurial.

Comment: Revision control, eh? Thanks a million, that's exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Use a [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/) folder.  If you use Eclipse, just put the entire folder in the Dropbox folder, and you are set to go with a backup-ed IDE.

Added bonus: access your project from anywhere.

You could also use [GitHub](https://github.com/), but then your source code will be open to the community unless you pay for one of their "plans".

Also, consider using [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/), which isn't known as well, but is free.  (Thanks to A--C for that alternative to GitHub)

Comment: Which is why you use https://bitbucket.org/ instead of GitHub for private repos with less than 5 people working on the repo.

Comment: +1 on the Dropbox idea. Saved my arse overwriting DWG files at work many times. Its upload history (or whatever you call it) will keep track of all previous revisions of a file.

One thing to consider is what the saving architecture of your IDE is. For example, does it save before compile, save synchronously, save on user command? For this reason, using a VCS would be a good idea.

Comment: Using Dropbox as version control is a ***terrible*** idea.  You don't have any notion of history with that.

Comment: I recommend using an IDE with Dropbox for that reason.  Also, you can recover deleted files with Dropbox.  And I gave other ideas besides that, so if you could remove your downvote @Makoto, that would be nice.

Comment: I'd feel more comfortable if the idea about Dropbox were removed.  It's nifty to have your files in the cloud, but again - you don't get the benefit of history with that alone.  That's enough to make it an undesirable answer.

Comment: I'm in first year of a games course. I'm only running a main method and a few class files at the moment. I use a vanilla text editor (Textpad) to code and compile because the IDEs are a bit too much at the moment. I would like to be able to store locally as well as online for the times my internet goes down.